# Footer on each PDF page using HTML/CSS and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf-generation, google-chrome-headless

I am using Chrome headless to convert HTML/CSS to PDF.

Is it possible to create a footer that will be displayed on each page (after rendering as pdf) on the bottom without overlapping with other HTML elements?
I tried a few possible solutions and so far none have worked properly.
The important thing to note is that I cannot predict the height of all HTML elements as they are filled with dynamic content.

What didn't work:

1. This code is making the footer display in proper place on each page, however other HTML elements are overlapping with the footer.

   ```
   @page {
     size: A4 portrait;
     margin: 1.5cm;
   }

   #footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
   }
   ```
2. This code is cutting part of the footer (the part that doesn't fit on the page is moved to the top of the next page)

   ```
   @page {
     size: A4 portrait;
     margin: 1.5cm 1.5cm 5cm 1.5cm;
   }

   #footer {
     page-break-inside: avoid; /* this setting has no effect */
     position: fixed;
     bottom: -1.5cm;
   }
   ```
3. This seems to have no effect at all on the footer's positioning

   ```
   @page {
     size: A4 portrait;
     margin: 1.5cm;
     @bottom-center {
         content: element(footer);
     }
   }

   #footer {
     position: running(footer);
   }
   ```

Is there any way to make a footer that would properly render in Chrome?

Comment: For anyone struggling with this, I have implemented a way around that problem.
I used HummusJS to render the footer on the already generated PDF document. Just left some margin for it